# Fabricar etiquetas anidadas en React JS

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Me gustaría saber como puedo realizar lo siguiente en React JS utilizando componentes JSX. Crear un componente que pueda recibir dentro otro componente, por ejemplo el componente padre y el componente hijo tal que así:

```
<Padre>
    <Hijo description="Hello Word"/>
</Padre>
```

Y quede por ejemplo como:

```
<div class="padre">
    <div class="hijo">
        Hello World
    <div/>
<div/>
```

Comment: Para pasar datos de un componente a otro en React, como en tu ejemplo ese string `Hello Word`, se utilizan las `props`. No son muy difíciles de usar, acá en esta documentación se explica cómo funcionan [React Props](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_props.asp). No sé si es eso lo que estás buscando.

Comment: No en realidad, no es lo que estoy buscando :/

Comment: Vamos, quieres de un componente padre envie datos a un componente hijo?

Comment: Pasa que es un poco difícil entender lo que necesitas porque el tipo de ejemplo que utilizas es un poco confuso. Si lo que estás buscando es pasar todo un componente dentro de otro componente, quizás podría servirte aprender a usar la prop `children`. Acá hay otro articulo y un video que explican cómo usarla: [Children en React](https://ewebik.com/react-js/children). A lo mejor eso se acerca más a la respuesta a tu pregunta.

Comment: Eso si es lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias.

Comment: Perfecto. Como ese articulo que te mandé hace parecer a `children` más complejo de lo que realmente es, agrego como respuesta un sencillo ejemplo práctico para aprender a usarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para usar todo el contenido de un componente dentro de otro componente podemos usar la prop `children`.

Usarla es más fácil de lo que parece.

Simplemente rodeamos de la etiqueta `<Padre>` al componente `<Hijo />` y luego desde el componente `<Padre>` recibimos todos los datos del `<Hijo />` que se guardarán en la prop `children`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Padre>
        <Hijo />
      </Padre>
    </div>
  );
}

const  Hijo = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Hello world</p>
    </div>
  );
}

const Padre = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3>
        Mostrando contenido de "Hijo" desde "Padre": 
        {children}
      </h3>
    </div>
  );
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Ahí desde el componente `App`, usamos a `<Padre>` pasándole el valor de `<Hijo />` que en este caso es el párrafo que dice "Hello world".

De esa forma, mediante `children`, en el componente `<Padre>` recibimos ese "Hello world" que viene de `<Hijo />` y lo imprimimos dentro de un `<h3>`.

Ejecuta el código, y mira ese resultado.